# Is that a correct usage of present perfect?

Tags: grammaticality, past-tense, questions, present-perfect

What do you think about this sentence?

> Do you have bought the lesson book?

Is that a correct usage of "Do you have bought"? Or should I say "Did you buy"?

Comment: You first example is not valid English. "Did you buy" is valid, but maybe not ideal in context. Assuming it's a teacher who expects/wants his pupil to purchase the book, he'd probably say "Have you bought". This carries more of an implied *"...yet?"* following. Of course, he's much more likely to say "Have you **brought** the book", because he probably doesn't care whether the pupil *paid* for it or not - only that the pupil should have a copy so he can pursue his studies properly.

Comment: It's perhaps worth saying that American English tends to use the past tense in questions of this kind where British English use the perfect.

Comment: It does? I certainly don't.

Comment: In ‘The Cambridge Guide to English Usage’, Pam Peters gives these examples:

‘We already gave him a response.’ (American)
‘We have already given him a response.’ (British)

Comment: @Barrie: In answers of that kind, I believe Pam Peters is correct: Americans would tend to use the past. In questions like the O.P.'s, I believe Americans would tend to use the present perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As written, your sentence is not grammatically correct. In order to use the [Present Perfect](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/presentperfect.html), you should say:

> *Have you bought* the lesson book?

You are trying to ask if someone has *bought* the book, so the verb "to buy" needs to be in the right tense. You could also write,

> You have bought the lesson book?

But starting the sentence with "have" is a valid use of inversion in English, which denotes a question. "Do" does not add anything to the sentence, and is not part of the present perfect tense.

---

Now, should you use the Present Perfect here? You definitely can, because present perfect can denote the concept of unspecified time. You are not sure *when* or even *if* the person bought the book, so you are trying to figure that out by asking "have you..."